# CASE statement if no rows found | Oracle

Tags: oracle, case

I have a sample table with below data. i am using Oracle.

```
ID  Sales  STATUS
1    100   XX
1    50    XX
1    40    YY
```

I have to group the data on ID column having different status. I am using below CASE query

```
SELECT 
ID, 
sum(sales) SALES,
CASE 
WHEN STATUS='XX' THEN 'POSITIVE'
WHEN STATUS='YY' THEN 'NEGATIVE'
END INDICATOR
from 
sample_table
group by 
ID,
CASE 
WHEN STATUS='XX' THEN 'POSITIVE'
WHEN STATUS='YY' THEN 'NEGATIVE'
END;
```

The above statement is giving me correct output which is

```
ID    SALES    INDICATOR
1     150      POSITIVE
1     40       NEGATIVE
```

Now if i change the data to below

```
ID  Sales  STATUS
1    100   XX
1    50    XX
1    40    XX
```

The query used above is giving only POSITIVE indicator row as there is no YY STATUS in the table. I want to display 0 SALES even if there are no status YY for the same ID.

```
OUTPUT
ID   SALES   STATUS
1    190     POSITIVE

Desired output
ID   SALES   STATUS
1     190     POSITIVE
1     0       NEGATIVE
```

is it possible to have the desired output? It's a rare scenario for my data but i still want to handle it.  Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a `PIVOT`, then `UNPIVOT` combined with `NVL` so that you always get a positive and negative indicator for each ID.

**Case 1**

```sql
WITH
    sample_table (ID, Sales, STATUS)
    AS
        (SELECT 1, 100, 'XX' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, 50, 'XX' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, 40, 'YY' FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT id, NVL (indicator_pos, 0) AS indicator_pos, NVL (indicator_neg, 0) AS indicator_neg
          FROM (SELECT ID,
                       SALES,
                       CASE
                           WHEN STATUS = 'XX' THEN 'POSITIVE'
                           WHEN STATUS = 'YY' THEN 'NEGATIVE'
                       END    INDICATOR
                  FROM sample_table)
               PIVOT (SUM (sales)
                     FOR INDICATOR
                     IN ('POSITIVE' AS indicator_pos, 'NEGATIVE' AS indicator_neg)))
       UNPIVOT (sales FOR INDICATOR IN (indicator_pos AS 'POSITIVE', indicator_neg AS 'NEGATIVE'));

   ID    INDICATOR    SALES
_____ ____________ ________
    1 POSITIVE          150
    1 NEGATIVE           40
```

**Case 2**

```sql
WITH
    sample_table (ID, Sales, STATUS)
    AS
        (SELECT 1, 100, 'XX' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, 50, 'XX' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, 40, 'XX' FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT id, NVL (indicator_pos, 0) AS indicator_pos, NVL (indicator_neg, 0) AS indicator_neg
          FROM (SELECT ID,
                       SALES,
                       CASE
                           WHEN STATUS = 'XX' THEN 'POSITIVE'
                           WHEN STATUS = 'YY' THEN 'NEGATIVE'
                       END    INDICATOR
                  FROM sample_table)
               PIVOT (SUM (sales)
                     FOR INDICATOR
                     IN ('POSITIVE' AS indicator_pos, 'NEGATIVE' AS indicator_neg)))
       UNPIVOT (sales FOR INDICATOR IN (indicator_pos AS 'POSITIVE', indicator_neg AS 'NEGATIVE'));

   ID    INDICATOR    SALES
_____ ____________ ________
    1 POSITIVE          190
    1 NEGATIVE            0
```

Comment: EJ Egyed, Nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the dummy data to handle this scenario -

```
SELECT ID, 
       SUM(sales) SALES,
       CASE WHEN STATUS='XX' THEN 'POSITIVE'
            WHEN STATUS='YY' THEN 'NEGATIVE'
       END INDICATOR
  FROM (SELECT ID,
               sales,
               STATUS
          FROM sample_table
        -- ADDING A DUMMY ROW
         UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT ID, 0, 'YY'
          FROM sample_table)
 GROUP BY ID,
          CASE WHEN STATUS='XX' THEN 'POSITIVE'
               WHEN STATUS='YY' THEN 'NEGATIVE'
          END;
```

Comment: Although if you have zero 'XX' rows, now you'd need to add a second dummy row. I think it would be better to do `SELECT DISTINCT ID, 0, STATUS FROM sample_table`

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ID, 0, STATUS FROM sample_table` wouldn't add the necessary rows because if ID 1 only has XX statuses, then the YY dummys wouldn't get added. Adding these dummy rows could also cause performance issues if the table is very large querying it 3 times just to add dummy potentially necessary dummy rows.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways to solve this. I like starting with defining the columns I want to always appear, and then outer joining the table to use for aggregate queries.

```
WITH
    sample_table (ID, Sales, STATUS)
    AS
        (SELECT 1, 100, 'XX' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, 50, 'XX' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, 40, 'XX' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 50, 'YY' FROM DUAL)
SELECT 
ID2, 
sum(nvl(sales,0)) SALES,
CASE 
WHEN STATUS2='XX' THEN 'POSITIVE'
WHEN STATUS2='YY' THEN 'NEGATIVE'
END INDICATOR
from 
(select distinct t1.id id2, t2.status status2 
    from sample_table t1 cross join sample_table t2) base_table
left outer join sample_table on id=id2 and status=status2  
group by 
ID2,
CASE 
WHEN STATUS2='XX' THEN 'POSITIVE'
WHEN STATUS2='YY' THEN 'NEGATIVE'
END
order by 1;
```

Output:

```
       ID2      SALES INDICATOR
---------- ---------- ---------
         1          0 NEGATIVE 
         1        190 POSITIVE 
         2         50 NEGATIVE 
         2          0 POSITIVE
```

Comment: This would not work in all cases. In your sample data, if you change ID 2 to XX, then the NEGATIVE rows disappear from the result. Also, cross joining a table on itself just to do distinct could be very expensive if the table is large.

Comment: I think we have different opinions about what working correctly would entail. This approach is dynamic, assuming that all status values of interest exist in the table. It will also show values which are not 'XX' or 'YY' - which may or may not be desirable. Your approach is static and requires manual specification of all pivot columns. They're both useful.

Comment: True, both could be useful. I think your query could also be considered static since your case statement would need to be updated if there were ever a status like ZZ it would return a null value in your INDICATOR column.